# The part of the view after an `extend` statement is not rendered

Tags: view, web2py, extend

I'm trying to use the `extend` keyword to add a comment-box (a view placed under `default/comment_box.html`) across several of my views, by:

```
...
<hr/>
{{extend "default/comment_box.html"}}
<span id="master">
...
```

But, when this executes, all the part of the view after the `extend` statement is not being rendered and all I'm getting is:

```
...
<hr/>
<!--Content from the Comment-Box-->
```

As you can see, the part after the `extend` statement, i.e. `<span id="master">` has gone missing. The Web2Py [examples](http://web2py.com/examples/default/examples#example_3) seem to be doing it the same way. Am I missing something here? Why is it truncating abruptly after the `extend` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
{{include 'default/comment_box.html'}}
```

If you use `{{extend 'default/comment_box.html'}}`, the comment_box.html view must contain an `{{include}}` directive somewhere, in which case, the content of the extending view gets included in place of that `{{include}}` directive. On the other hand, if you simply want to include the contents of comment_box.html within your view, you need to use `{{include 'default/comment_box.html'}}`.

See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/5#Page-layout) for more on `extend` and `include`.